# Can you change the questions asked based on the delivery mechanism

Tags: surveymonkey

I am building a survey using Survey Monkey that may be sent out via email as well as other channels such as a link in a web page or community or a Tweet.  One of the questions asks if the responded would like us to follow up with them in more detail so we need to capture their contact info.  That's easy enough if we email it to them as the survey will automatically capture their email address.  However, if they have followed a link instead of responded from the email that won't happen.  So, I want to be able to recognize that the survey responses come from a source other than email and then ask for contact info.  If it's a response to the email survey I don't want to bother the respondent with asking them that info.

So, can I configure the survey to not display the page asking for contact info if the survey is sent via email.

Answer (score 0):

No, the survey design cannot be impacted by the collection method. You would need to create two separate surveys and merge the results outside of SurveyMonkey.